# C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'

Tags: c#

I am trying to pull files in a directory where the selected path in the combo box item is selected.

I'm used to vb.net and when doing a split in C# I get error message below:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'

I want to get all the files and then for each file add the filename to a listbox.

Anyone can point me in the right direction or let me know what I am doing wrong in split.

Here is the code:

```
private void cbLogFileLocations_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(cbLogFileLocations.SelectedItem.ToString());

    foreach (string file in Files)
    {
        string[] strSplittedFileName = file.Split(@"\");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can post your code here in your question.

Comment: You passed a `string` to [a method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___) that expects `Char`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use single quotes if you are going to split on a character, so change to this:

```
//You have to escape the back slash or use the ampersand on the front
string[] strSplittedFileName = file.Split('\\');
```

OR if you want to split using a string:

```
//When splitting by a string, 
//you need to pass a string array and an Enum of StringSplitOptions
string[] strSplittedFileName = file.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to vote up but thanks the first one helped. Cheers

Comment: @Breau No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Please in the future make sure to include source code in post: the reason being that link rot happens etc and it's always nice to use as reference for people having the same issue as you.

As alluded to in a previous answer using the char representation in C# (string literals) will invoke the overload that accepts a char.

From: `mystring.Split(@"\")`
To: `mystring.Split('\\')`

If you are attempting to split by new lines rather use:

```
Environment.NewLineChar
```

Comment: Thanks for the info much appreciated.

Comment: Good luck Breau. Apologies that I didn't take time to compile before sending.